# Objective C Reflection - Extracting Property name

Tags: objective-c, reflection, nsstring

I'm trying to figure out a method of extracting a property name given an Object, not all properties' names, but a specific one. In order to do that I've implemented this method in my class:

```
-(NSString *)keyForProperty:(NSObject *)theProperty{
unsigned int propertyCount = 0;
objc_property_t * properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &propertyCount);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < propertyCount; ++i) {
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];

    NSString *name=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];

    NSObject * propertyValue=[self valueForKey:name];
    if(propertyValue==theProperty){
        free(properties);
        return name;

    }
}
free(properties);

return nil;

}
```

This works like this: I've and object foo of class A to know the name of the property p I do something like that:

```
NSString *name=[foo keyForProperty:foo.p];
```

The problem is that in my class A I've two properties p1 and p2 both NSStrings, and in A's init method I assign @"" to both of them. The problem is that p1 and p2 then point to the same memory position, and therefore when I do:

```
 NSString *name=[foo keyForProperty:foo.p1];
```

and

```
 NSString *name=[foo keyForProperty:foo.p2];
```

I get the same result for both of them.
Any idea on how to prevent this from happening while assigning @"" to both properties?
Do you see any better way of implementing this? The requirements are that given and object:

```
 A* foo=[[A alloc]init];
```

of class A I've to be able to get a particular property name.

Thank you.

**Explanation on why I need this:**

I've a UIViewController subclass TextEditingVC that all it does is it recieves and object to edit and the property name to edit and the edition process is managed automaticly by the TextEditingVC instance, all I've to do is:

```
A *foo;

//lets edit property p
NSString *key=[foo keyForProperty:foo.p];
TextEditingVC *theVC=[TextEditingVC alloc]initWithEditableObject:foo withEditionKey:key];
//present theVC in some way
```

This TextEditingVC should be able to edit any object's NSString properties. The idea is to make TextEditingVC as general as possible since in my application I've to edit NSString that are properties of various classes.

Ofcourse I could simply use:

```
NSString *key=@"p";
```

instead of:

```
NSString * key=[foo keyForProperty:foo.p];
```

but in that case the string would be hard coded in my code and I would like to avoid it, for the sake of good programming practices, or am I wrong in trying to avoid hard coded strings in this particular case?

Comment: I do not yet understand what you are trying to achieve. Why do you want to call `NSString *name=[foo keyForProperty:foo.p1]` instead of `name = @"p1"`? - And you can never expect that all properties of an object have different values. - Perhaps you can give a better example how that method would be used.

Comment: This sounds *exceptionally* fragile.  Doing pointer comparisons on the value returned from `valueForKey:` is not a good idea.

Comment: I agree with you, it is fragile, that's why I'm experiencing some problems... I'm kinda looking for a better solution, any ideas? I've updated the post with some extra explanations on why I need this

Comment: @Mppl: But in `key=[foo keyForProperty:foo.p]` you also hard code the property name (as "p" in `foo.p`). - I still fail to see why this is more general than `[TextEditingVC alloc]initWithEditableObject:foo withEditionKey:@"p"]`.

Comment: As a matter of fact I don't think I do: lets say tomorrow I want to change the property name from p to x, all I've to do it to go the refactoring tool in Xcode and change p to x in the class defenition, no need to look for @"p" strings in my code to replace with @"x", you're right about something being hardcoded anyway, but my way is more easly mantainable isnt it?

Comment: It not more general at all, its fundamentally the saem in terna of generality, I think. Do you see any other way of implementating the same thing, other than this one with @"p" or without it?

Comment: @Mppl: OK, I understand now what you want, but I don't know a solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way of achieving quite what you want. However, you could perhaps make access using hard-coded key names somewhat safer. For example, you might make a macro like:

```
#define CHECKED_PROPERTY(obj, prop) ((void)((obj).prop), @#prop)
```

This macro expands to an expression using the comma operator. First the `obj.prop` sub-expression is evaluated, but its result is discarded. The point of this is just to make the compiler validate the expression, so it will complain if `prop` is not a valid property of `obj`. The second sub-expression stringifies the `prop` argument using the `#` preprocessor operator. It prefixes it with `@` to turn the string literal into an Objective-C `NSString` literal.

And use it like so:

```
NSString* key = CHECKED_PROPERTY(foo, p);
```

This expands to:

```
NSString* key = ((void)((foo).p), @"p");
```

This evaluates `foo.p` but ignores the result and has the effect of setting `key` to `@"p"`.

Then if you refactor and rename `p` to `x`, either the refactor engine (if it's really smart) will figure out that it needs to do something with the above, or at least the compiler will complain if the refactor misses it. (This falls down if you rename `p` to `x` and `q` to `p`, though.)

Comment: I dont quite undersatand what this macro is doing... Could you please explain it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have been clearer. I have updated the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Thank more clearer now. That did the trick. Any way of avoiding the nasty compiler warnings on the obj.prop not being used?

Answer (score 0):

You can init differently your both properties (p1 = @"v1", p2 = @"v2")

Comment: I would like very much to be able to avoid this solution. I would like @"" to be assigned to both properies